# Identification of an Australian pigeon in the NT

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

This pigeon was spotted in Darwin, NT, Australia. I am not able to solidly identify it using my books or google searches. My best bet is a [Torresian Imperial Pigeon](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~BAJAN/Pigeons/Torresian%20Imperial%20Pigeon%20or%20Nutmeg%20Pigeon%20or%20Torres%20Strait%20PigeonSQSQS.jpg) ([Birds of the NT website](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~BAJAN/AlansBirdsOfNT.htm?Pigeons)).

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other pictures?  Torresian Imperial Pigeon seems like a fair guess, but a better shot of the beak,  feet, or -- more importantly -- its tail feathers or covert feathers could help confirm that.

Comment: @theforestecologist - I know! But unfortunately this is the only pic I have from the bird. A pity for sure. The tail of the imperial pigeon is black and that seems a strong marker imho, but I don't have it on camera.

Comment: I'm just not sure too many other species are all white with black under the wing like that. The next best guess is the closely related Pied imperial pigeon. That species  is more concentrated in SE Asia,  but seems to show up in zoos worldwide, so could be an option in Northern OZ

Comment: @theforestecologist - Thanks for all your feedback. I'm not an ecologist - I'm a fake Biologist as I always say (i.e., a medical one) - so please feel free to vote to close if it is too unclear.

Comment: I've expanded upon my comments to make a full answer. Hopefully it provides some closure :p.

Comment: @theforestecologist - He&& yeah mate, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bird appears to be an Imperial Pigeon of the [*Ducula* genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_pigeon). Based on the limited angle of the lone picture of your specimen, my best guess as to the species is the [**Torresian Imperial Pigeon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torresian_imperial_pigeon) (*Ducula spilorrhoa*).

[image]

The species is a relatively large, [pied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piebald) species of pigeon found in various habitats (forest, woodland, savanna, mangrove and scrub) in Australia (including in the Northern Territory where you saw your specimen), New Guinea and nearby islands.

You can see more pictures, videos, and calls [here](http://www.hbw.com/ibc/species/torresian-imperial-pigeon-ducula-spilorrhoa), as well as additional info [here](http://www.hbw.com/species/torresian-imperial-pigeon-ducula-spilorrhoa).

Your specimen is unlikely the closely related  [Pied Imperial Pigeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_imperial_pigeon) (*Ducula bicolor*) because:

1. *D. bicolor* is a  [Southeast Asian species](http://www.oiseaux.net/maps/pied.imperial.pigeon.html)
2. *D. bicolor* has a [bluish grey beak](http://rosamondgiffordzoo.org/assets/uploads/animals/pdf/PiedImperialPigeon.pdf), whereas your specimen and *D. spilorrhoa* both have a yellow beak.

   Note: Your specimen is also unlikely [*Ducula subflavescens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowish_imperial_pigeon) because the feathers are white and not [yellow](https://i0.wp.com/www.birdlife.org/images/sized/400/369-yellowish-imperial-pige_andy_bunting.jpg.jpg), and it is unlikely [*Ducula luctuosa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver-tipped_imperial_pigeon) because that species is endemic to only a few islands.